# GCC Debug issue in ARM Keil

Tags: debugging, gcc, keil

I've written and compiled a simple C program to be simulated on ARM CM7 microprocessor within ARM Keil IDE (CMSIS Core 4.3 & GNU Tools ARM Embedded 4.9 2015.q2). The program compiles without any warnings or errors. Yet, when debugging through the ARM Keil the program gets stuck at `system_ARMCM7.c` file at the line

```
SystemCoreClock = SYSTEM_CLOCK;
```

Checking the "Performance analyzer" component of the Keil I can see the program is stuck at the `_exit` function/module of the `system_ARMCM7.c` file.

Unfortunately I can't figure out what is causing the issue.

Comment: What is "the issue"? That the debugger isn't always 100% accurate about which instructions are associated with which source lines (which is to be expected, really), or that your program has finished executing (either returned from `main()` or called `exit()` directly)?

Comment: @Notlikethat The issue is that the debugger does not even reach to the first instruction of my program at gets stuck at the initial startup and system instructions.